# Z-test with no relevant sample size as I have a Gaussian probability distribution

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, kullback-leibler, z-test, divergence

I have two Gaussian curves, there are not samples, these are just probability distributions essentially. So I can do a Gaussian fit on them, or also a weighted average and weighted variance on the data, and I have get the mean and variance values.
I would like to calculate some sort of measure that describes how different the two Gaussian curves are. Of course, the first thing that came to mind is the z-test, as it considers both the changes in the mean and the variance between the two curves, and spits out a single z-value to describe it. This is exactly what I want (as ultimately I want to be comparing the z-values of the 2 gaussian curves that I compute under different conditions). Problem is that the z-test equation has the sample number in there, which is not relevant to my case. Is there a way to do this, or is there another metric I can use?

Thanks

Edit:
Example of the curves. My goal is to have a metric that describes the difference between the two curves, so that I can vary the input variable to maximize the difference between the output distributions.

[image]

Edit:
So this is actually kernel density estimation, so my data is as far as I understand is binned and each bin has some probability associated with it, when all the bins and probabilities are integrated they add up to 1. Unfortunately, the two distributions don't have the same bin size.
Example:

| Bins | Kernel Probability Estimate |
| --- | --- |
| 1.10659307 | 0.007532385 |
| 1.107679891 | 0.007805255 |
| 1.108766712 | 0.008086891 |
| 1.109853533 | 0.008377697 |
| 1.110940354 | 0.008678085 |

Comment: When you say that you `have two Gaussian curves`, what do you mean by that? Do you have the functions describing them? If so, why are you "sampling" from them?

Comment: _I would like to calculate some sort of measure that describes how different the two Gaussian curves are_ you could use the KL divergence or any other divergence measure between the two pdf. But the real question is: what will you do with it?

Comment: Regarding the two Gaussian curves, I am simulating the output if my system, but some of my input variables have a distribution associated with them (experimental uncertainties) therefore the output ends up having a distribution. It is not exactly Gaussian, but I can fit a Gaussian on it for simplicity. So I am trying to investigate under what system parameters are the output distributions the most different. So, the output is just the output variable vs what probability it has to occur. I do not know the function, but I can fit Gaussian or polynomial curves on it, that will give me a function.

Comment: This KL divergence looks very interesting, I will look into. I am not a stats background so will need some time to figure out how I can compute it from my data. As long as I have some sort of metric that describes how different the distributions are, that is all I need, because then I can maximize that metric to figure out under what conditions I get the most difference, which is my goal. On another thought, a very primitive approach could be to calculate the area overlap of the two Gaussians, the less the overlap the more different they are, or am I wrong?

Comment: Given that you don't have a stats background, it would be really better if you describe the overall problem you are trying to solve and why do you think maximising differences will help you. this all sounds like an [XYProblem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I have a sensor. The baseline output of the sensor with no analyte has a distribution because of the experimental variance of system variables (temperature etc). With the analyte, the sensor output changes, but still has a distribution. I am trying to identify the conditions at which the distribution with and without analyte are the most different. I can calculate the kernel probability estimates of the sensor with and without analyte for any set of conditions. I want to have a metric that represents the difference between the before and after states, so I can maximize it.

Comment: But you have data, not Gaussian distributions, right?

Comment: Quite clearly neither of the depicted curves is actually a picture of a Gaussian distribution; both are right skew. Are these curves you've drawn coming from data or are they purely theoretical constructs? If they're theoretical, *what function did you draw?* If data, explain what was actually observed and exactly how that data was converted to curves

Comment: If you can't see the skewness just by looking you can always just flip the images over and see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbKjW.png

Comment: Yes you are right, they are not Gaussian, I just wanted to simplify my question, as there is quite a bit a detail. The curves are coming from simulated data. I essentially have a model of the system and I generate the kernel density estimate via Monte Carlo Analysis. They are not meant to be symmetric, the shapes and features will depend on how the input parameters affect the output parameter (and these are strongly coupled and non-linear relations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Kullback-Leibler Divergence (KLD) is a popular tool for measuring the "distance" between distributions

KLD is defined as
$$D_{KL}(p || q) = E_X\left(\log\left(\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\right)\right)$$

For continuous distributions, this expected value is found via integration. If your data had the same bin locations $x_1, \ldots, x_B$, then this could be computed as
$$\hat D_{KL}(p||q) = \sum_{i=1}^Bp(x_i)\log\left(\frac{p(x_i)}{q(x_i)}\right).$$

Instead, I will suggest an alternative which relies on two facts

1. Given a KDE, we can draw samples (Silverman 1985, `ks` package)
2. Given two sets of (independent) samples, we can estimate the KLD between the two underlying distributions (Perez-Cruz & Fernando 2008, `quack` package).

#### R Code

Suppose that $p$ is a standard exponential distribution and $q$ is a Gaussian with mean $3$ and sd $2$. Data is simulated from these distributions and we are given only the KDE's from these samples.

```
library(ks) #install.pacakges("ks")
z1_private <- rexp(100, 1)
z2_private <- rnorm(100, 3, 2)
d1 <- kde(z1)
d2 <- kde(z2)
```

Now we use the approach of Silverman (1985) to sample from these KDE's

```
n <- 1000
z1 <- rkde(n, d1)
z2 <- rkde(n, d2)
```

Finally, we can use Perez-Cruz & Fernando (2008) to estimate the KLD.

```
library(quack) #devtools::install_github("knrumsey/quack")
quack::kld(z1, z2)
```

For the seed `set.seed(12345)`, this returns an estimate $\hat D_{KL}(p || q) = 1.22305$ which is **very close** to the true value found in Perez-Cruz & Fernando.

#### Note on Symmetry

As @Dave mentions in a comment, KLD is not a symmetric distance (indeed, it is not a proper distance at all). I should have made this clear. One option is to consider the "symmetrized KLD" which is given by
$$\frac{D_{KL}(p||q) + D_{KL}(q||p)}{2},$$
which is sometimes referred to as Jeffrey's Divergence.

```
(quack::kld(z1, z2) + quack::kld(z2, z2))/2
[1] 1.270173

# Or alternatively
quack::kld(z1, z2, type=2)
```

Another option, if symmetry is important to you, is to look at [Kolmogorov-Smirnov Distance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#:%7E:text=The%20Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov%20statistic%20quantifies,distribution%20functions%20of%20two%20samples.) This is given simply by the largest difference between the output of the empirical CDFs.

```
xx <- seq(min(c(z1, z2)),
          max(c(z1, z2)),
          length=1001)
max(ecdf(z1)(xx) - ecdf(z2)(xx))
```

Of course, interpreting any of these distances is hard on its own and is primarily meaningful in context of other similar distances.

#### References

Silverman, B. W. "Two Books on Density Estimation." (1985): 1630-1638.

Pérez-Cruz, Fernando. "Kullback-Leibler divergence estimation of continuous distributions." 2008 IEEE international symposium on information theory. IEEE, 2008.

Comment: +1 KL divergence was one of my first ideas. My concern is that there isn't symmetry. When one is an obvious reference distribution, that's fine, but for comparisons in general, I find that problematic.

Comment: @Dave, a fair point! There is of course, the symmetrized version $[D(p||q) + D(q||p)]/2$, but perhaps one would be concerned about interpreting this measure.

Comment: @knrumsey This response is legendary. So as per the comment of Dave, do you think using the symmetric measures are better for comparisons? I think I do not need to interpret the measure, as long as the measure I get from one set of KDEs (before and after analyte is introduced to the sensor at system conditions 1) compare well to sets of KDEs from other systems conditions, I am very happy.  I don't quite understand what the symmetry implies here, I understand the assymmetry is D(p||q) is not equal to D(q||p), but I don't understand how that lack of symmetry is problematic for comparisons.

Comment: @knrumsey Do you have any tips as to how to turn my KDE data into a KDE class object? The rkde function only takes a KDE class object (list of 12). I can't really run the kde function on my data as that would be a kernel density estimate of a kernel density estimate. I guess I would need to manually create the KDE class object, or perhaps somehow work backwards to generate sample data on which if I run the kde function it spits back the kernel density data I already have?

Comment: @DominikDuleba Symmetry is one of the 4 properties of a proper distance measure. Without it, it's a little unclear what you're measuring, since the order you choose for $p$ and $q$ may affect your results. Jeffrey's Divergence addresses this, but note that it is still not a proper distance since (I think) it does not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @DominikDuleba I think you have two choices, you'll have to try to manually create KDE class objects or you'll have to look through the Silverman paper and try to implement the method on your own.  The main thing you need, is to generate samples based on the KDE info that you do have.